# Why is the energy cost functional mostly defined as $u.u^T$?

Tags: optimal-control, robotics

In optimal control theory, while minimizing the energy of a say mobile robot, the expression for the cost functional is generally $u.u^T$ where $u$ is the control vector. I searched why the energy term is defined the way it is but couldn't find any answer. Can anyone please explain why it is defined like this?

Comment: A reason this might be a frequent form to express the cost function is that it is equivalent to squaring and summing over the vector terms to obtain a scalar value, i.e. $u.u^T = \sum_i u_i^2$

Comment: Loosely relates to the way energy is defined in physics, for example Kinetic  Energy of an object is defined as $KE=\frac{m*u^2}{2}$, where $m$ is its mass and $u$ its velocity